# I got an import error using iamport module

Tags: python, import

I just `pip install iamport-rest-client`, `from iamport import Iamport` and got the error.
In the github example, there is `from iamport import Iamport`.
But I got **the error above:**

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iamport' from partially initialized module 'iamport' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I don't know about modules and such **git**s, so please tell me what's wrong with my code. Thanks.

Comment: You should show all your code.

Comment: @WaketZheng It's all. I just did `from iamport import Iamport`.

Comment: Did you activated virtual environment?

Comment: @WaketZheng I think i did not. How can I activate it?

Comment: https://docs.pipenv.org/    or  https://python-poetry.org/